# PHP MYSQL - Anti Multi Account

Tags: php, mysql, unique-constraint, unique-index

I need to make an anti-multi account, i found this example for the mysql query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49bea0/1 that, is that a good way to do it?

If there are other simple ways to do, please let me know this is really important :(

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. What do you need to do, prevent duplicate entries or simply select distinct entries?

Comment: I need to check if there are multi-users with the same ip, to ban them. but i will use php

Comment: There is no easy and clear way to stop multi-accounting, user could use a VPN and another browser for account A and another VPN and browser for account account B

Comment: @far2005 i'll have some logs if the user have multi-ip in a short period, might be suspicious, but if i can build a standart check for the ip, its already a good way to start.

Comment: Also you need to take into account the situation when the IP of a mobile user changes when he moves

Comment: also there are shared internet connections, so that multiple users could have the same IP

Comment: May be you can use browser fingerprint instead IP for this matter

Comment: @GuyFawkes as i said, user can use multiple browsers and VPNs, you have to rely on users mistake

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev browser fingerprint is sometime illegal depending of your country , in mine this is a grey tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to reject attempts to sign up for accounts if they come from an IP address that already has an account.

The comments have raised the question of whether this is a good idea. It is not. For one thing it's easy for a user to change IP addresses. For another thing, some companies and universities have thousands of users sharing a single public-network IP address (look up *NAT router* to learn more). Even two different home users in the same household share a single IP, so I can have an account and my partner can't.  So allowing only one account per IP address is an unnecessary and insufficient security measure.

But that's not what you asked. You asked how to do it with SQL. Here's how.

Let's say you have a table called `users` with a column called `ip_address`.

Create a unique index on that column.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX no_dup_ip ON users (ip_address);
```

Then, when you try to use an INSERT statement to add a new user -- a new row to your `users` table -- it will fail if it  has the  same IP address as any existing user.

You will get MySQL error 1062, with a text error message looking something like this.

> Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '192.0.2.210' for key 'no_dup_ip'.

You can detect this error with the PDO or mysqli error reporting functions, and get your php program to say something polite to your would-be user.

Comment: This response exactly answers your need / but in some case you will lose account .
if different people connect from company or school, behind same router meaning same ip, the first will success, but others will never subscribe account.